# GroovyScriptExecutionException Whenn Trying to use lat_lon: true inside geo_points mapping in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I was using geo_point type in elasticsearch and i defined its mapping as this

```
location          : {"type":"geo_point"},
```

now when i was trying to use script_ields like this

```
script_fields : {
      distance : {
        script : "doc['location'].arcDistanceInKm(12.34,23.12)"
      } 
    }
```

Everything was working fine but now when i changed my mapping type to this for indexing lats and longs also (because i want to use bounded box now)

```
location          : {"type":"geo_point", "lat_lon":true},
```

now when i am trying to use above script i am facing below error

```
GroovyScriptExecutionException[ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No field found for [location] in mapping with types [restaurant]]]
```

Where restaurant is the type of my index.

Now can anyone please tell me why i am getting this Error and how can i solve this It will be really really helpful if you guys just put just a little light on this problem.

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: facing same problem ??

Comment: Works for me. How did you index the location? Give a sample document.

Comment: var body_merchant = {
          mappings : {
            shop_type: {
              properties:{
                location          : {"type":"geo_point"}
              }
            }
          }
}

client.indices.create({
      index: "merchanty",
      type: shop_type,
      body: body_merchant,
  }, function(err,resp,respcode){
      console.log(err,resp,respcode);
});

Comment: i am working in node.js with elasticsearch

Comment: And how does one document look like?

Comment: below is one document                                                                                                "_source":{"jeb_no":"wood000","timestamp":"2015-09-23T02:24:40+05:30","total_ratings":0,"total_reviews":0,"total_improvements":0,"rating":0,"shop_name":"woodstock restaurant","shop_type":"restaurant","location":{"lat":21.34,"lon":21.34},"address":{"street":"street 3, D Block","area2":"Manipal County","area1":"Singasandra","city":"Bangalore"}}},

Comment: Works for me. In your mapping you have `shop_type: { properties:{ location : {"type":"geo_point"} } }`. Why does the exception refer to `restaurant` type but your mapping shows `shop_type` as the type?

Comment: in parameter i am passing restaurant dont worry that is not the issue mate

Comment: Ok then, mate. It works for me. If you care to share the complete mapping and complete query, please use a gist and share the link. Otherwise, I don't see a problem with what you have now as it works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90378/discussion-between-aman-verma-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: can you please come in a discussion with me please

Comment: @AndreiStefan actually what i think is that when indexing the document you are passing lats and longs as strings [lat, lon]but i am passing them as object {"lat": lat, "lon":lon} can you please tell me in my case how can i use script to get the distance

Comment: I am passing them like this ` "location": {
    "lat": 41.3994375,
    "lon": 2.16152349999993
  }`.

Comment: ok thnx may be problem is somewhere else, hey why you are leaving from discusiion everytim ??

Comment: how can this be possible that when you are using doc['location'] you are geting whole array i mean as it's an object ??

Comment: hey @AndreiStefan you were damn right man actually what was happening is that i thought type will be shop_type value but it was taking "shop_type" as type thanx a lot really you told me very first but i thought problem was somehwere else well finally removed my error :)

Comment: :-) you didn't want to listen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mapping you have `shop_type: { properties:{ location : {"type":"geo_point"} } }`. Why does the exception refer to `restaurant` type but your mapping shows `shop_type` as the type?

You may want to check the correctness of your query and make sure the right type is being queried.

Comment: one more thing can you please tell me how can i use minimum_should_match: 0 in a bool query ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747122/query-only-for-increase-scoring-in-elasticsearch if you know anything about it then please help me ??