# Query only for increase scoring in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to write a query in elasticsearch only for scoring can anybody please tell me how can i do that my query is given below also "minimum_should_match": 0 is not working with should, if any query matches both area2 and area1 then i want to boost the score of the result now how can i achieve that can anybody tel me the final query which i should write ??

```
query: {
                    bool: {
                      must: [
                          {
                            query_string: {
                              query: shop_search,
                              fields: ['shop_name'],
                              boost: 30.0
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            bool: {
                              should: [
                                {
                                  term : { 'address.area2' : search_area2 },
                                  term : { "address.area1" : search_area1 }                                  
                                },
                                "minimum_should_match" : 0,
                              ],
                            }
                          }
                      ] 
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get all records that match the shop search and boost the results where the the address.area1 and/or address.area2 field values match the area searches?

The syntax you are using for the `bool` is off.  The match clause needs to be fixed up to fit Elasticsearch's expectations and the extra nested `bool` should not be necessary.  See [Elasticsearch Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "query" : <SHOP_SEARCH>,
                    "fields" : ['shop_name']
                }
            },
            "should" : [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "address.area1" : {
                            "query" : <SEARCH_AREA1>,
                            "operator" : "and",
                            "boost" : <CUSTOM_BOOST1>
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "address.area2" : {
                            "query" : <SEARCH_AREA2>,
                            "operator" : "and",
                            "boost" : <CUSTOM_BOOST2>
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I think with that query, you can expect the the following:

- only results that match the shop search
- results that do not match on the area fields but do match the shop search - this is due to the presence of the match clause
- order of the results will generally be results that match both areas first, followed by results that match one of the areas, followed by results that match neither of the areas - but no guarantees.  Learn more about Elasticsearch scoring

You might want to review everything you are getting with [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

Comment: first can you tell me now where can i  apply scoring factor and i want to use area1 and area2 with "AND" operator also i want my shop_name search query to execute first then my area query ??

Comment: Well, before all that, can you answer the following?  1). Why/to which sub query do you want to apply a scoring factor?  2). When you say you want the "AND", does that mean you want to match all words for each of the areas?  3).  What do you mean by can your shop name query execute first?  I think that might be an odd way of saying something else that I am not getting.  Anyway, I updated the answer slight so that there are more details that you can choose to fill in the query.

Comment: I hope that is what you meant with the "AND" operator thing (just "and" op on the match query), since you did have that strange minimum_should_match : 0 aspect in the original question.

Comment: now listen what i want to do for every shop with shop_search as shop_name if they are in (area2 and area1) to increase the score of the shop_name but if they are (in only area1 or area2 or neither) then i do not want to do anthing now do u get it as now you will see that after fetching the shop i want to search for areas that'sy i was asking to query shop_search first and then for areas  ??

Comment: That is what the bool query will do.  You can added custom boosts to help that along.

Comment: can you please write that for me ??

Comment: Hmmm... that is what I did up there.  Perhaps, create a sample index, try it out, get some results, and post what did not work so well for you?

Comment: thanks for hanging in there till now for me actually in your should query if one query matches then boost will be given but i want to give the bost when both area1 and area2 matches now i hope u got my point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90575/discussion-between-aman-verma-and-eemp).